# Format output file from a bash script into HTML table format

Tags: html, linux, bash, awk, format

I have a script that gets data from multiple sources and I want to format its output to HTML table format.

Edited:

The format at the moment:

```
[Environment Name]
[Back end version]
[DB Version]
[event1 status] [event2 status] [event schema] [nodes] [node_no] [vpool] [ver] [node_ip]
```

The list at the moment:

```
grid-dev
BE version: 6.0
Database version: 10
DISABLED DISABLED  dev_1  3  01  1  10.0.19-MariaDB  10.101.666.11:3306
grid-test
BE version: 7.0
Database version: 11
ENABLED  ENABLED  test_1 2  02  4  10.0.17-MariaDB  10.108.777.14:3306
grid-test
BE version: 7.0
Database version: 11
SLAVESIDE_DISABLE  SLAVESIDE_DISABLE  test_2 1  02  3  10.0.17-MariaDB  10.108.777.47:3306
grid-staging
BE version: 6.0
Database version: 10
DISABLED  DISABLED  staging_1  2  02  4  10.0.18-MariaDB  10.109.888.22:3306
```

and I want to format it to HTML table in something like this

```
   ENVIRONMENT  BACKEND_VERSION  DB_VERSION  EVENT1    EVENT2    SCHEMA  NODES  NODE_NO  VPOOL  VERSION          IP
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    grid-dev      6               10        DISABLED  DISABLED    dev_1    3       01      1   10.0.19-MariaDB  10.101.666.11:3306
    grid-test     7               11        ENABLED   ENABLED     test_1   2       02      4   10.0.17-MariaDB  10.108.777.14:3306  
    grid-test     7               11        SLAVES... SLAVESI...  test_2   2       01      3   10.0.17-MariaDB  10.108.777.47:3306                             
    grid-staging  6               10        DISABLED  DISABLED    stag_1   2       02      4   10.0.18-MariaDB  10.109.888.22:3306
```

Is it possible to do it using bash script ?  Any help will be appreciated I am new to bash and HTML so I am stuck.

My attemp using the code on the answer:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "ENVIRONMENT  BACKEND_VERSION DB_VERSION  EVENT1 EVENT2  SCHEMA NODES NODE_NO VPOOL VERSION IP" } NF==1{env=$0; t=1; next;} t==1{t++; be=$3; next;} t==2{t++; db=$3; next;} t==3{printf "%s %s %s %s\n", env, be, db, $0; env="#";be="#";db="#";}' < "$output" | column -t  | tr '#' ' ' >> "$dbstats"
```

The out put is

```
ENVIRONMENT   BACKEND_VERSION  DB_VERSION   EVENT1             EVENT2             SCHEMA              NODES  NODE_NO  VPOOL  VERSION                             IP
    grid-dev56.0  136              grid_dev  Database            version:            138
                                                DISABLED            DISABLED            grid_systest     3      03       1      10.0.19-MariaDBgrid-systest56.0
                                                Database            version:            138
                                                SLAVESIDE_DISABLED  SLAVESIDE_DISABLED  grid_systest     3      01       1      10.0.19-MariaDBgrid-systest56.0
                                                Database            version:            138
                                                SLAVESIDE_DISABLED  SLAVESIDE_DISABLED  grid_systest     3      02       1      10.0.19-MariaDBgrid-staging56.0
                                                Database            version:            136
                                                SLAVESIDE_DISABLED  SLAVESIDE_DISABLED  grid_staging     3      03       1      10.0.19-MariaDBgrid-staging56.0
                                                Database            version:            136
                                                SLAVESIDE_DISABLED  SLAVESIDE_DISABLED  grid_staging     3      02       1      10.0.19-MariaDBgrid-staging56.0
                                                Database            version:            136
                                                ENABLED             ENABLED             grid_staging     3      01       1      10.0.19-MariaDBgrid-production56.0
                                                Database            version:            136
                                                SLAVESIDE_DISABLED  SLAVESIDE_DISABLED  grid_production  3      03       1      10.0.19-MariaDBgrid-production56.0
                                                Database            version:            136
                                                SLAVESIDE_DISABLED  SLAVESIDE_DISABLED  grid_production  3      02       1      10.0.19-MariaDBgrid-production56.0
                                                Database            version:            136
                                                DISABLED            SLAVESIDE_DISABLED  grid_production  3      01       1      10.0.19-MariaDB
```

Thanks

Comment: How is that table html ? Do you mean you want HTML to be generated that will create that table ?

Comment: I want to convert my list into HTML table format. I have this output being generated on a bash script.

Comment: probably would be easier to modify the generating bash script which already has the context.. could you post this script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print "Envirnoment  BackEndVersion DBVersion  EventName  Status  Schema" } NF==1{env=$0; t=1; next;} t==1{t++; be=$3; next;} t==2{t++; db=$3; next;} t==3{printf "%s %s %s %s\n", env, be, db, $0; env="#";be="#";db="#";}' <input_file | column -t | tr '#' ' '

Envirnoment      BackEndVersion  DBVersion  EventName  Status    Schema
grid-dev         6.0             10         swap       DISABLED  dev_1
                                            busy       DISABLED  dev_1
grid-test        7.0             11         swap       ENABLED   test_1
                                            busy       ENABLED   test_1
grid-staging     6.0             10         swap       DISABLED  staging_1
                                            busy       DISABLED  staging_1
grid-production  5.0             9          swap       ENABLED   prod
                                            busy       ENABLES   prod
```

After you edit your question with your attempts, Please comment on this answer, so that I will add explanation.

Comment: I am impressed now I can get a really well format and send to another file. Do you have any idea on how to put this into a HTML table using awk ?
Thank you so much for that.

Comment: ^^ Edit my one liner script above. You can generate HTML without too much efforts.

Comment: if you have time could you share the explanation for that code, I am really keen to know what is going on this awk statement. Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With the format above is possible to get into a HTML format using:

```
awk -v header=1 'BEGIN{OFS="\t";  print "<html><body><table>" }
{
        gsub(/</, "\\&lt;")
        gsub(/>/, "\\&gt;")
        gsub(/&/, "\\&gt;")
        print "\t<tr>"
        for(f = 1; f <=NF; f++)  {
                if(NR == 1 && header) {
                        printf "\t\t<th>%s</th>\n", $f
                }
                else printf "\t\t<td>%s</td>\n", $f
        }
        print "\t</tr>"
}

END {
        print "</table></body></html>"
}' "$FORMATED_TABLE" )
```

This could be useful for someone looking to convert into HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a late answer to this question, but will help those googling for a solution, for converting bash command output to html table format. There is an easy script available to do this at : https://sourceforge.net/projects/command-output-to-html-table/ which can be used to convert any command output or file to a nice html table format. You can specify the delimiter to this script, including special ones like tabs, newlines etc. and get the output in html table format with a html search at the top.

Just download the script, extract it and issue the following command :

```
cat test.txt | { cat ; echo ; } | ./tabulate.sh -d " " -t "My Report" -h "My Report"  > test.html
```

This assumes that fields are separated by a space character, as specified by the other solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/31245048/16923394

If the delimiter is a tab character, then change -d " "  to  -d $'\t' above.

The output file generated is attached here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/my-project-files/files/test.html/download

Comment: Can you include the script or a part of the script to explain your answer ?